# My object stored in s3 is automatically downloaded when accessing the url

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When uploading my file to s3, I upload it publicly, but when accessing it through its URL, the file is downloaded automatically, what I want to achieve is to be able to view it in any browser without having to download it.
I upload it through node.js, I attach the code

```
fs.readFile(dataString, (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  var parametrosPutObject = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: dataString,
    Body: data,
  };
  s3.putObject(parametrosPutObject, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("recorded file");
    //obtenerURL();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide a `Content-Type` header for the file that browsers interpret as viewable-in-browser.

If the object is e.g. a JPEG file, providing `Content-Type: image/jpeg` should clue browsers in that they don't need to download the file.

Comment: hi, the files are .pdf and in chrome they download automatically and in firefox not. The content-type do I add together with the upload?

Comment: Yes, adding something like `Headers: {'content-type': 'application/pdf'}` to your `parametrosPutObject` should do the trick.

Comment: I read the documentation and added

ContentType: 'application / pdf'

but they continue to download automatically

Comment: Then it may be up to your browser's settings. If the browser is set to always download PDFs, you can't override that.

Comment: @EnzoPaez `ContentType: 'application / pdf'` would not be expected to work, because that is wrong.  The correct value is `'application/pdf'` without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your data is available publicly and can be open in your browser without getting downloaded. You can modify the bucket ACL policy with below snippet.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::Bucket-Name/*"
    }
  ]
}
```